# Type deduction while using universal references

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference, lvalue, type-deduction

Can someone help me to understand why the output of the following code

```
template< typename T >
void check()
{
  std::cout << "unknow type" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void check<int>()
{
  std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void check<int&>()
{
  std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void check<int&&>()
{
  std::cout << "int&&" << std::endl;
}

template< typename T >
void bar( T&& a )
{
  check<T>();
}

int main()
{
  bar(0);

  int a = 0;
  bar( a );
}
```

is

```
int
int&
```

and not

```
int&&
int&
```

From my point of view, it seems more intuitive that an r-value reference remains as an r-value reference and an l-value reference an l-value reference, However, it seems that only l-value references remains as l-value references and r-values become non-reference values.
What is the motivation/idea behind this?

Comment: You're using `check<T>`, not `check<T&&>`; why would you expect the `&&` to be there when you explicitly omit it?

Comment: I expected that `bar(0)` is the same as `bar<int&&>(0)`. When replacing in my code above `bar(0)` by `bar<int&&>(0)`  then the output is actually `int&&\n int&`.

Comment: The type of `bar<T>` is `void(T&&)`, the type of `bar<T&&>` is `void(T&& &&)` (before reference collapsing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bar(0);` calls the specialization `bar<int>(int&&)` i.e. `T` is deduced as `int`, so `check<T>()` is `check<int>()`. The parameter type is `T&&` which is `int&&`, but that's the type of the parameter, not the type `T`.

This is entirely consistent with non-forwarding references. If you define:

```
template<typename T> void baz(T&);
```

and you call it with an lvalue of type `int` then `T` is deduced as `int`, not `int&`

The only thing that's special about forwarding references like your example uses is that for `T&&` the type can be deduced as an lvalue reference, call it `R`, in which case the parameter type is `R&&` which is the same as `add_rvalue_reference_t<R>` which is just `R`. So for the call `bar(a)` you call the specialization `bar<int&>(int&)` i.e. `T` is deduced as `int&`

When you call `bar<int&&>(0)` with an explicit template argument list there is no argument deduction, and so `T` is substituted by `int&&`, so the parameter type `T&&` is `add_rvalue_reference_t<int&&>` which is just `int&&`.